# Trouble with Scanner taking data from a command line using Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I will admit, this is a school assignment... But I simply cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

I have a hash table with an insert function. The following code is supposed to take a line of data from `System.in` in the format "Long String" (i.e. "32452 John").  The first token must be a Long for the ID number, and it must be followed by a String token for the name. When I run the program and I get to the portion where this must be executed (It is in a `switch` statement), I entered 'a' and hit enter. The command line immediately reads "Invalid value." (note: not VALUES, as that would mean it hit the nested if statement.  It won't let me type in any data.  Thank you in advance!

```
System.out.println("Enter ID and Name.");
//temp to take in the next line entered by the user 
//inScan is the Scanner for System.in
temp = inScan.nextLine();
//Create Scanner for the line
Scanner tempScan = new Scanner(temp);
if(tempScan.hasNextLong()){
   thisID = tempScan.nextLong();
   if((tempScan.hasNext()) && (thisID>0)){
      thisName = tempScan.next();
     //The data will only be inserted if both segments of data are entered
      myTable.insert(new Student(thisID, thisName));
   }else{
      System.out.println("Invalid values.");
   }
}else{
   System.out.println("Invalid value.");
}
```

Comment: So which is the problem, the program saying `Invalid value` (and not "values"), or the program not asking for ID and Name again?

Comment: can you pls post entire code..

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the second `Scanner`?

**Example**

```
String input = scanner.nextLine();

String[] tokens = input.split(" ");
Long id = Long.parseLong(tokens[0]);
String name = tokens[1];
```

And if you wanted to add your validation:

```
String input = scanner.nextLine();
if(input.contains(" ")) {
    // You know there's a space in it.
    String[] tokens = input.split(" ");
    if(tokens.length == 2) {
        // You know it's a value, followed by a space, followed by a value.
        if(tokens[0].matches("[0-9]+")) {
            // You know it only contains numbers. 
            Long id = Long.parseLong(tokens[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not run it, but i guess your problem is that when you enter the text 'a' and hit enter, this line is false:

```
if(tempScan.hasNextLong()){
```

as you haven't entered a number. hence why it drops to the next block. If you enter something numerical first, i suspect your code with work. you probably need to add a 'while' loop around it, to run until it gets a number.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a Scanner which reads from System.in, there's no need for another one. The second one you've made is a scanner for a String, which will never have a nextLong as it has nothing to scan after your String.

I won't write any code for you as this is homework, but stick to your original scanner when checking for user input instead.